# Generated excel file does not have extension

Tags: java, excel, report, reporting

I am trying to generate excel file using the following approach:

```
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/form-data";
private static final String FILE_NAME = "DemoReport";
private static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";

public MultipartFile export(final UUID uuid) throws IOException {
    final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");
    int rowCount = 0;

    final List<ProductDTO> productList = productService
            .findAllByCategory(categoryUuid);

    writeTitles(sheet.createRow(rowCount++), titles); // private method

    // code omitted

    final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(FILE_NAME, FILE_EXTENSION);

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggingUtils.error("error... ", e);
    }

    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = FILE_NAME.concat(FILE_EXTENSION);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
}
```

However, the generated file has no extension (its type is File). So, what is the problem that causes this and how to fix?

Comment: Is this within some test or why are you using `MockMultipartFile`? (I don't know that class but "mock" would not be a term I'd expect in production code).

Comment: What should I use instead of `MockMultipartFile` ?

Comment: Well, having a look at the Javadoc (it's Spring, right?) there seems to be the `CommonsMultipartFile` implementation of `MultipartFile`.

Comment: I use Spring, yes. But I have no idea why previously `MockMultipartFile` was used in our project. When I replace it with `MultipartFile`, I see that I also need some other changes e.g. parameters, but I have no idea as I am new in Java. Any example please?